# Rails query to group by date range

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to group set of objects that are scoped by filters by monthly.

Current Database associations:

```
`Customer has_many Invoices and Invoice belongs to customers
 Store has_many customers and invoices`
```

This gets called inside the service object which returns all the clients that meet certain criteria

```
`store.new_clients_with_purchases_between("1/1/#{date.year}".to_date, 
"1/#{12}/#{date.year}".to_date.end_of_month)`

`new_clients_with_purchases_between` function is inside store model

`def new_clients_with_purchases_between(start_date, end_date)
    bw_customers.made_purchases_between(start_date, 
  end_date).where.not('bw_customers.id' => 
  customer_ids_with_purchases_before(start_date))
 end`
```

And `made_purchases_between` function is inside `Customer Model`

```
`scope :made_purchases_between, -> (start_date, end_date) { 
joins(:bw_invoices).distinct.where('bw_invoices.purchase_date >= ? 
AND bw_invoices.purchase_date <= ? AND bw_invoices.subtotal > 0 AND 
bw_invoices.purchase_date < ?', start_date, end_date, Date.today) }`
```

I am trying to group them by purchase rate in each month

```
`-----------------------------
[id][mon][year][numMon][count]
     jan   2017   1        10
     feb   2017   2        10`
```

and so on...

My current code

```
`store.new_clients_with_purchases_between("1/1/#{date.year}".to_date, 
"1/#{12}/#
```

{date.year}".to_date.end_of_month).select("purchase_date").select('purchase_date, COUNT(*) as count').group("purchase_date")`

which gives me all of the purchase_date and count with out grouping by month

Is there a way to accomplish some like the above?

thank you so much for your help